# How can I change the order of cycling windows in Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, customization

When there are multiple instances of the same application running, each with its own window, the Unity launcher shows one icon for all of them.  Then you have to click on that icon to go the "first" of those windows and click again to choose any other.  So far so good.

What is annoying to me is that this "first" window is not the last that I've been working with.  So I have to bring up the entire list again and click on the desired one.  This is particularly disturbing when you are switching back and forth between two specific windows and have others that are not as frequently used.  Is there a way to adjust the behavior to what I like?

I appreciate any hint.

Comment: This bug has been driving me nuts.  When 11.04 first came out it worked correctly.  But shortly afterward an update came out that introduced the new annoying behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those things are getting massive attention for 11.10, but in 11.04, that's not configurable and won't be fixed. Luckily, 11.10 is only a couple of months away :)